# How can I gradually morph one list into another (cartesian product of 2 lists)?

Tags: python

Say I have two lists,

```
one = ['a1', 'b1', 'c1']
two = ['a2', 'b2', 'c2']
```

I want to generate a collection of all possible combinations of these items, without changing their positions in their respective lists. So for the example above, it'd be:

```
['a1', 'b1', 'c1']
['a1', 'b1', 'c2']
['a1', 'b2', 'c2']
['a2', 'b1', 'c1']
['a2', 'b2', 'c1']
['a2', 'b2', 'c2']
```

I'm looking through `itertools` hoping to find something that matches this description, but I haven't found one yet.

Comment: How might you approach this problem with ordinary `for` loops?  Can you make a more specific statement about the form of the output; for example, what is the first element, and what is the second element?

Comment: Itertools permutations does this. But you will have to maybe filter it slightly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `product` but you need to set it up first. The problem is that you have your values "sideways"--you want to put all possible values for the first position together, then those for the second, etc. You can "transpose" your data with the `*zip()` maneuver.

```
from itertools import product
list(product(*zip(one, two)))
```

The result from that is

```
[('a1', 'b1', 'c1'),
 ('a1', 'b1', 'c2'),
 ('a1', 'b2', 'c1'),
 ('a1', 'b2', 'c2'),
 ('a2', 'b1', 'c1'),
 ('a2', 'b1', 'c2'),
 ('a2', 'b2', 'c1'),
 ('a2', 'b2', 'c2')]
```

If you really want lists rather than tuples, use

```
[list(v) for v in product(*zip(one, two))]
```

which gives you

```
[['a1', 'b1', 'c1'],
 ['a1', 'b1', 'c2'],
 ['a1', 'b2', 'c1'],
 ['a1', 'b2', 'c2'],
 ['a2', 'b1', 'c1'],
 ['a2', 'b1', 'c2'],
 ['a2', 'b2', 'c1'],
 ['a2', 'b2', 'c2']]
```

Note that these are not exactly what you listed as the desired output, since you left out a couple of possibilities.

Comment: I was going to walk through the logic step by step, but this summary is enough.  Deleted my answer draft.  :-)

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks!